# Detecting the corners of an incomplete shape with OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

I'm working on a program to detect the edges of a shape on a page, and then crop and wrap the image to zoom in on the shape. However, the problem is that my shape is bound by only a marker on each corner. Following is an example image that I am trying to work with:

[image: Example]

How would I be able to determine the corners of the image? I've tried a contour analysis, and even a feature matching algorithm, but none of them give me the reliability that I need.

As I'm new to CV in general, is there a handy function that is capable of solving my exact problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Due to variable lighting, I added an example image of what I'm trying to deal with:

[image: Image Raw]

Comment: have you checked out `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()`?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()`. you can literally copy/paste the code from the openCV docs [LINK](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_shi_tomasi/py_shi_tomasi.html)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('test.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 16, 50, 50)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(blur, 40, 0.1, 10)
corners = np.int0(corners)

for i in corners:
    x,y = i.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1)

plt.circle(img, (x, y), 3, 255, -1)
plt.show()
```

This is what I get[image: results]

you may want to play with the bilateral filter and the goodFeaturesToTrack  parameters.

Another option would be to use a match filter of your corners (that way you don't get all the hits on the words).

Comment: I tried using the good features to track, but the second I took a real world photo (from a phone or something similar), the gradients in the lighting really gave the goodFeaturesToTrack a hard time.

Comment: I see. good illumination makes processing a lot easier, but the BilateralFilter can help a bit. Can you share one of these real world images?

Comment: I modified the original post and included an example image.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is find all the contours in the given image using [`cv2.findContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html), Then find the bounding rect of each contour and find the minX, minY, maxX, maxY among all the contour rects, this will give you a outer bounding rect which covers all the smaller contours and hence your desired results.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("/Users/anmoluppal/Downloads/mjut8.png", 0)

# Threshold and Invert the image to find the contours
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find the contours
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

x, y, r, b = [img.shape[1]/2, img.shape[0]/2, 0, 0]
# Iterate over all the contours, and keep updating the bounding rect

for cnt in contours:
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if rect[0] < x:
        x = rect[0]
    if rect[1] < y:
        y = rect[1]
    if rect[0] + rect[2] > r:
        r = rect[0] + rect[2]
    if rect[1] + rect[3] > b:
        b = rect[1] + rect[3]

bounding_rect = [x, y, r-x, b-y]

# Debugging Purpose.
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (r, b), np.array([0, 255, 0]), 3)
```

[image]